# Find the minimum $n$ such that $x^3-\frac{2\sqrt2+1}{2}x^2+\frac{2\sqrt2+1}{2}x-1\mid x^n-1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Set $f(x)= x^3-\frac{2\sqrt2+1}{2}x^2+\frac{2\sqrt2+1}{2}x-1$. Next I found the roots of this polynomial that $x=1$ and $\frac{1}{2}(\frac{2\sqrt2 -1}{2} \pm i \frac{\sqrt7+1}{2})$. Here the $n$ is a natural number.

But I can't proceed the next step. What should I do to find the minimal value of the $n$ without any just calculation (long division)? The method not finding roots also welcomed.

Comment: Have you tried De Moivre's formule?  $z^n =1$, where $z$ are the complex roots.

Comment: I believe you have error in expression for second and third roots and I believe answer 8 is wrong.

If polynomial is divisor of $x^n-1$, then all roots of this polynomial must satisfy $x^n=1$, then all roots must have form $\cos \frac{2k\pi}{n}+i\sin\frac{2k\pi}{n}$. Then you should represent your roots in form $\cos\phi+i\sin\phi$, with $\phi=\frac{2\pi k}{n}$.

Comment: First root is 1. Sum of three roots is $\frac{2\sqrt2+1}{2}$, then sum of conjugate roots is $\frac{2\sqrt2-1}{2}$, then real part of conjugate roots is $\frac{2\sqrt2-1}{4}$. Product of three roots is $1$, then product of conjugate roots is 1, then absolute value of conjugate roots is 1. Then argument of conjugate roots is $\pm\arccos \frac{2\sqrt2-1}{4}$. I believe there is no natural number $n$ such that $n\arccos \frac{2\sqrt2-1}{4}=2k\pi$.

Comment: Are you sure the question is correct? Given that the answer is $n=8$, the question ought to be finding the smallest $n$ such that $(x^3 - (1+\sqrt{2})x^2 + (1+\sqrt{2})x - 1)\mid (x^n-1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is wrong, in that the $f$ given in the question does not divide $x^n -1$ for any positive $n$. Let $f$ be a monic cubic of the form
$$f(x) = (x-1)(x^2-2cx+1)=x^3 - (1+2c)x^2 + (1+2c)x - 1$$ such that $c$ is quadratic over $\mathbb{Q}$ and such that $f\mid(x^n-1)$.
Since $c$ is quadratic over $\mathbb{Q}$, the corresponding roots of unity are algebraic of degree $4$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. But by the [totient function formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial#Fundamental_tools) for the degree of cyclotomic polynomials, such is the case only if the roots are $n$th roots of unity for $n=5,8,10,12$, so that the only polynomials of the prescribed form that divide some $x^n-1$ are
$$\begin{align}
f_{5\pm}(x)&=(x-1)(x^2\mp(\tfrac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2})x+1) \\
f_{8\pm}(x) &= (x-1)(x^2\mp\sqrt{2}x+1) \\
f_{10\pm}(x) &= (x-1)(x^2\mp(\tfrac{\sqrt{5} + 1}{2})x+1) \\
f_{12\pm}(x) &= (x-1)(x^2 \mp\sqrt{3}x+1)\text{.}
\end{align}$$
But the $f$ of the problem statement
$$f(x)=(x-1)(x^2-(\sqrt{2}-\tfrac{1}{2})x + 1)$$
is not on this list.